# What is a simple expression for $\sum\limits^m_{j=1}(m-j)2^{j-1}$ and a combinatorial interpretation of it?

Tags: combinatorics

$$f(m)=\sum^m_{j=1}(m-j)2^{j-1}$$ I've to understand what is a simple form of $f$ by computing some value of it, but I can't see a simple form of it, can anyone help me? I have also to give a combinatorally and inductive proof of the equality; with the inductive I think I won't have problems, but I'm not so good with the combinatorally proof, can any of you help me, please?

ok I got it, $f(m)=2^m-m-1$. Now I have to count the elements of a certain set in 2 ways to prove the equality, but I don't have any idea.

Comment: Have you tried splitting the summation into two summations, for $m 2^{j-1}$ and $-j 2^{j-1}$, and solving those separately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT You are asked to find a combinatorial (or, bijective) proof of the identity $$ 2^{m}-m-1 = \sum_{j=1}^m (m-j) 2^{j-1} .$$

The left hand side counts the number of <del>sets</del> subsets of $\{ 1,2, \ldots, m \}$ with at least $\ldots$ elements. (Fill in the blank.)

Let us count the same thing in another way. Let $S$ be the set that we are trying to pick. Suppose that the *second* largest element of $S$ is $j$. Then,

- How many elements of $S$ are strictly larger than $j$? In how many ways can you pick those elements?
- We also need to pick the elements of $S$ that are strictly smaller than $j$. In how many ways can you do this?

Comment: It probably helps to point out that in this argument we’re choosing $S$ from the set $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$.

Comment: @Brian Oh, of course. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @ Srivatsan: Thanks, it helped.

Comment: @Alex Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

If you compute the first terms, you get

> 0, 1, 4, 11, 26, 57, 120, 247, 502, 1013

and you look for that in the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/Seis.html), you get to [this page](http://oeis.org/A000295) which informs you that the sequence is the sequence of Eulerian numbers, gives you various formulas for the numbers and lots of references where you will find more information.